# Javascript counter to change hyperlink text color

Tags: javascript, html

I have a image carousel with pre and next... Also there are hyperlinks the go along with the images being shown. How can I get the hyperlinks to change red when the related image is shown?

I was thinking a counter to identify/related the image the and hyperlink

Comment: And what does your mark-up look like?

Comment: I've got a counter working when a image is clicked but don't know how to the count number relate to the text hyperlinks

Comment: <a href="#" id="gallery-next"><img src="MAIN_IMAGES/right.png" alt="" /></a></div> ////that'f for the next button (my counter js is not included)/// here is my hyper links  <a class="ex1" href="#">ZOOM FORCE I BOOT ///</a>

Comment: Please provide more information or make an example showing the aspects of the problem.